# Android efect animation on click

Tags: android, xml

I've been searching for an easy way to make a cube effect animation when a button is pressed but my search yielded nothing. The idea is that when a button is pressed the text of the button changes after a cube animation is displayed. Does anyone know how something like that can be achieved? Is there maybe a function that helps me do that? Keep in mind I am still a beginner so I am looking for an easy way to it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Android API has "animators" which are responsible for animation of either object properties or values. I'm a bit unsure if this cube you're trying to animate is a shape or just an image view but I am assuming it is an image view. Therefore, this url should help.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html